# Send JSON keys specific only for frontend work from server or not?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, database, rest

I am working on frontend side of the project (Vue.js) and my colleague is now on vacation - shes doing backend + DB.

The project is in Typescript and I work with array of some objects, let's call them "selections"

```js
interface Selection {
   title: string
   edit: boolean
}
```

The edit is just for me on frontend - it signals if user changing the title right now and my question is:

Is common practice to specify the interface as is and send the default value from backend? Like:

```json
{
   "title": "xyz",
   "edit": false
}
```

OR

send just DB data from backend,

```json
{
   "title": "xyz"
}
```

while specify interface as `edit?: boolean` (optional)
and add the key/value (edit: true) when it's needed?

```js
interface Selection {
   title: string
   edit?: boolean
}
```

Will be thankful for any opinions on this.

Comment: Storing a volatile frontend-only value in the backend doesn't make much sense I guess. But your colleague is the only person who can answer this (also, asking for opinions happens to be OT)

Comment: I meant not to store them in DB - but send them in json in rest api call.
So yep - it will be stored in backend method that send the data.

Comment: Why send them if they aren't stored or needed?

Comment: The only but quite strong reason is because the object is defined that way in TS so I don't need to keep looking if the value is there or not. It's always there.
It's my first TS project, so I ask here :)

Comment: Just send it along then, additional data shouldn't trip up the backend.

Comment: I thought so too. The default value is always false, it could be just part of the method on backend that sends the data and frontend code will be less error prone I think. Thank you.